# C# Error: Unassigned local variable error when using "switch"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

What I want to achieve is, to show count of lines ending with/starting with (user selects type by comboBox1) given character (by textbox1).

Trying to compile this code:

```
string needle=textBox1.Text.Trim(), cboxSelection = comboBox1.Text;
int count;
switch (cboxSelection)
{
    case "Starting with":
        count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^" + needle + ".*$"));
        break;
    case "Ending with":
        count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$"));                    
        break;
}
string strCount = count.ToString(); // error line
label6.Text = "There are " + strCount + " lines " + cboxSelection + " " + needle + " character.";
```

Getting error message: `Use of unassigned local variable 'count'`. What am I missing?

Comment: Read the error message again. When can this be true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of unassigned local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110251/use-of-unassigned-local-variable) (It is for "if", but it's the exact same idea as here. The -1 is because there too many too-close matches.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your local `count` variable has not been definitely assigned at the point of use. Either declare it as

`int count = 0`;

or add a `default` clause to your case statement:

`default:
    count = 0;`

Your `switch` statement is not guaranteed to enter either case, so `count` can remain unassigned. If one of the two cases is required, you should throw an exception in your `default` case:

```
default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid selection");
```

You should always use a `default` case in your switch statements either to assign a default or to guard against unexpected states.

Comment: The problem is, now I'm getting result only 0.  How do you think is there any problem with `count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$")); ` line?

Comment: @epic_syntax - The problem is your `cboxSelection` variable is not guaranteed to match either case you have, so `count` will not necessarily be assigned in the case block.

Answer (score 2):

`Count` isn't assigned on all code paths. If your switch doesn't have "Starting with" or "Ending with", it will be `null`.

You can initialize it:

`int count = 0;`

Comment: Yes, I did it, The problem is, now I'm getting result only 0. How do you think is there any problem with count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$")); line?

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try with int count = 0;

and add ; not , between two instructions

string needle=textBox1.Text.Trim(); 
cboxSelection = comboBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Yes I tried, The problem is, now I'm getting result only 0. How do you think is there any problem with count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$")); line?

Comment: you can also use nullable type , try int? count = null;

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are not covering all possibilities within your switch... so there is a "path" in your code in which you get to `label6.Text` never assigning `count`.

You should either assign an initial value to  `count` or add a `default` to your switch

Comment: Fixed The problem is, now I'm getting result only 0. How do you think is there any problem with count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$")); line?

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement does not cover all cases (it realistically cannot, cboxSelection being a string), so there is a possibility that count does not get anything assigned to before you use it.

Add a default case to the switch to fix it.

Comment: Fixed, The problem is, now I'm getting result only 0. How do you think is there any problem with count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$")); line?

Comment: Have you tried to check your regex (e.g. at http://chris.photobooks.com/regex/default.htm)?