# "use of unassigned local variable" C#

Tags: c#

OK guys i'm sure there's something really silly i'm forgetting. i'm working on an app that calculates the cost of troops for Clash of clans just for kicks. i'm still pretty green to this whole programming thing. the barbTrainingCost after the comment "//calculate total cost for all barbs" is throwing me a "use of unassigned local variable" error.i know its a simple app but you have to start somewhere right? thanks for the help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populate the troop number combo boxes
            for (int i = 0; i < 240;i++) {
                BarbNumcomboBox.Items.Add(i + 1);
            }
        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Variables
            int barbTrainingCost;
            int barbTotal;
            int numberOfBarbs = BarbNumcomboBox.SelectedIndex + 1;

            //Find Cost of each barb
            if (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                barbTrainingCost = 25;
            }
            else if(barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1) {
                barbTrainingCost = 40;
            }
            else if (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 2) {
                barbTrainingCost = 60;
            }
            else if (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex ==3 )
            {
                barbTrainingCost = 100;
            }
            else if (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                barbTrainingCost = 150;
            }
            else if (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
                barbTrainingCost = 200;
            }
            else if (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 6)
            {
                barbTrainingCost = 250;
            }

            //calculate total cost for all barbs

            barbTotal = numberOfBarbs * barbTrainingCost;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `barbTrainingCost` doesn't have a value assigned in every case. If the `SelectedIndex` is not between 0 and 6 then the variable is uninitialized. You can set a default value when you declare it: `int barbTrainingCost = 0;` or make an `else` statement that will set the value if the `SelectedIndex` is not between 0 and 6.

Comment: What if `barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex == 7`?

Comment: When you put a breakpoint at the troubled line, what are the values of numberOfBarbs and barbTrainingCost?

Comment: @dustmouse breakpoints don't work so well when the code doesn't compile.

Comment: Similar  question was asked couple times (check "related" links). More precise duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110251/use-of-unassigned-local-variable?rq=1 (as it deals with similar `if` conditions), so one can reopen/close as different duplicate if this one is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to assign a value to your barbTrainingCost variable....
if you realize, you are declaring it, but never assigning a value outside any condition.... error is thrown because none of your if conditions its true so assignment never happens...

first, try to declare your variable with an initial value of zero... then you should work on why none of your IF clauses is hitting true....

```
int barbTrainingCost = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you always set your barbTrainingCost variable a value within an if statement (or else if) it can remain in an unassigned state by the time you use it in the calculation.

You can either set an initial value when you create the variable (var barbTrainingCost = 1;), change your final 'else if' to an else or add another else statement with your default.

As a separate note, because you are using a enum in your compare you could use a switch statement making your code cleaner to read.

```
switch (barbLvlComboBox.SelectedIndex)
{
    case 0: barbTrainingCost = 25; break;
    case 1: barbTrainingCost = 40; break;
    default: barbTrainingCost = 123;
}
```